# Get WiFi state and do operation on it using Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android

I am using broad cast receiver class in my app and i am doing operation on WiFi state in broad cast receiver class. if WiFi disconnects or connects then do some operation. when wifi connects its showing correct message but when wifi disconnects its not showing wifi disconnect message instead shows else statement.

Here is my code for Broadcast receiver class.

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "NetworkStateReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Network connectivity change");


        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            //check if wifi is connected
            if (ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Network " + ni.getTypeName() + " connected");
        }
        else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "wifi disconnected");
            }
            else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Network  else state");
            }
        }
```

registered in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

a Working Example

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

if (action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION))
{
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    NetworkInfo.State state = networkInfo.getState();

    if(state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
    {
        Log.d("Tag","Connected");
    }

    if(state == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED)
    {
        if(manager.isWifiEnabled())
        {
             Log.d("Tag","Disconnected");
        }
    }
    }

   }
```

Comment: thanks @Xäiñ Ul Abideen. but i need wifi disconnects condition.

Comment: there is no particulate to check if network is disconnected from wifi or Data

Answer (score 1):

Create Object of Wifi

```
wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Then

```
 if (action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION))
    {
 if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
        //perform action
    }
    else {
        //perform action
    }
```

Comment: i need wifi disconnects condition. i am saving wifi dissconnect time but problem ia when wifi connects it  first calls else condition and then calls if condition.

Comment: Try to use reverse condition

Comment: but i need both coditions if wifi connected and if wifi disconnected.

Comment: not working. I have tried your code. its not printing any condition